# Nodejs React - Facebook Login - Cors issue

Tags: node.js, reactjs, facebook, passport.js, passport-facebook

I am trying to implement facebook login with passport and FacebookStrategy.

```
passport.use(
    new FacebookStrategy(
        {
            clientID: 'myclientid',
            clientSecret: 'myclientsecret',
            callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3333/api/auth/facebook/callback',
            profileFields: ['email', 'displayName', 'name'],
        },
        async function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
            ...     
        },
    ),
)
```

Routes:

```
router.get('/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope: 'email' }))
router.get('/facebook/callback', passport.authenticate('facebook'), AuthControllerV3.loginFacebookWeb)
```

But when calling the endpoint `/facebook` from the client, I get this error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://www.facebook.com/v3.2/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3333%2Fapi%2Fauth%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&scope=email&client_id=myclientid'
> (redirected from 'http://localhost:3333/api/auth/facebook') from
> origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

I added in the client side this headers:

```
config.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
config.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = true;
```

But still getting this cros error.
What should I do. In facebook developers console I added in domain apps the domain http://localhost:3000 but nothing changed.

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a _response_ header, it is absolutely pointless to try and set it as a request header on the client side.

Comment: You _can not_ make background requests for the login dialog URL - you need to _redirect_ the user to it. Users need to be able to verify via the address bar, that they are actually entering their login credentials to Facebook, and not some phishing site.

Comment: @CBroe and you know how to approach that?? What should I do?